# When tracking changes, how can I change the name of who edited something on a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

When tracking changes, how can I change the name of who edited something on a Word document?

In my specific case, I worked on the document on different computers, and now tracked changes appear with several names and in several colors.  I want to convert these names to my own.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution I could think of:

- **Decline all changes** and save the document under an easy to remember name, like "document old.docx" (except those you'd like to keep as-is).
- Reload your document, this time **accepting all changes** and saving the document under a different name, like "document new.docx" (except those you'd like to keep as-is).
- Now go to the **Review** ribbon and select **Compare**, **Compare**.
- Follow the instructions on screen, picking your *old document* on the left (as *original document*) and your *new document* on the right (as *revised document*).
- You'll end up with a new document that has all the differences between both documents highlighted under your own/current name.

If you'd like a visual guide with screenshots, have a look at [this blog entry](http://technokarak.com/how-to-compare-two-documents-in-microsoft-word.html). Unfortunately I couldn't find any step-by-step guide in Microsoft's KB right now.

Comment: Won't this make him the owner of ALL the changes? I'm assuming other people are working on this document and have submitted changes.

Comment: Of course, this way he'll take "ownership" of all differences between both revisions. However, if there are changes he'd like to keep, he just has to not accept those. Going to update the answer.